# Get full accessable path from Android Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I need to access file from Android Gallery and upload it to the URL using POST.

There is no problem. I am just new to do this stuff like accessing device data. I need to have a hint to get full path of image what I selected from gallery using Intent and StartActivityForResult.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bt = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
}
```

Comment: Can you please share or refer some code to upload this bitmap to server using Post HTTP.

Comment: I recommend MultipartEntity, simple and powerful.